# CSS failed to load when using Route taghelper (Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ())

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So i was trying to route to this function using PostController

```
    [Route("Posts/{year:int}/{month:int}/{title}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Detail(int year, int month, string title)
    {
        var posts =_context.Posts.Where(x => x.PostedOn.Year == year && x.PostedOn.Month == month && x.Title.Equals(title));
        return View("~/Views/Posts/Details.cshtml", await posts.ToListAsync());
    }
```

The plan is to have the site return a page everytime the user click into a link

```html
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <a href="/Posts/@item.PostedOn.Year/@item.PostedOn.Month/@item.Title"><h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</h2></a>
    <p style="color:dimgrey">
        Posted  @Convert.ToDateTime(item.PostedOn).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss") with rate @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rate) by @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ViewCount) view(s)
    </p>
    <br />
    <p style="color:black; border-bottom:1px solid lightgrey">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)</p>
}
```

But when the link is click, only the correct data is shown, the site fail to load any image and CSS from wwwroot
[image]

Since i want to avoid using inline CSS, how can i fix this ?

I tried to use other methods to route like Map.Get but when Map.Get is used, all is returned is "{}"

Comment: You should check the network tab to see which url the css has loaded from your page to solve the issue.  Without this we couldn't know how to help you.